# Is there a way to change a print composer from A3 to A1 without having to re do all my txt boxes, arrows, annotations etc?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, scale

I am aware of how to change page size through page properties so thisis not my issue.
I have an a3 map prin composer with lots of txt boxes, annotations, arrows pointing to things etc, but when I change the scale to A1 they do not adapt to the page like the map does. It seems such a simple thing to do, surely I dont have to re position or re draw all my txt boxes and arrows?